# how to solve an error in console using reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So i have a component in react that I have created. When it's rendering it showing this error.

```
 Warning: Cannot update a component (`Inweight`) while rendering a different component (`StackPlan`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `StackPlan`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render
StackPlan@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:11659:19
TemplateWrapper@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:97205:24
TemplatesRenderer@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:97526:43
div
Form@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:102599:43
VisibilityPlan@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:13176:24
TemplateWrapper@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:97205:24
TemplatesRenderer@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:97526:43
div
Form@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:102599:43
form
div
div
Inweight@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:8449:92
WrappedComponent@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:5657:9
RenderedRoute@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:424426:7
Routes@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:425042:7
div
div
ScrollView@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:113534:43
div
div
Drawer@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:101149:43
div
SideNavOuterToolbar@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:6355:29
Content
App@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2126:62
div
NavigationProvider@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:5634:94
AuthProvider@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:5520:74
ThemeProvider@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:5767:23
Router@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:424984:7
HashRouter@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:423134:7
Root@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:2160:97
Provider@http://localhost:3000/static/js/bundle.js:420294:18 react-dom.development.js:74
    React 5
        printWarning
        error
        warnAboutRenderPhaseUpdatesInDEV
        scheduleUpdateOnFiber
        dispatchSetState
    handleStackData in-weight.js:49
    temporaryStacksJSON stackplan.js:289
    React 5
        basicStateReducer
        updateReducer
        updateState
        useState
        useState
    StackPlan stackplan.js:14
    React 9
        renderWithHooks
        updateFunctionComponent
        updateSimpleMemoComponent
        beginWork
        beginWork$1
        performUnitOfWork
        workLoopSync
        renderRootSync
        performConcurrentWorkOnRoot
    workLoop scheduler.development.js:227
    flushWork scheduler.development.js:205
    performWorkUntilDeadline scheduler.development.js:442
    <anonymous> task.js:57
    run task.js:34
    eventListener task.js:43
```

here inweight is my component that I want to use those props. I pass them through several components as props With out any change that has seen in the stack flow.
I want to solve this error.
this is my code

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import useGetAPI from '../getAPIS';
import apis from '../api-constants';
import { DataGrid, Column, Paging, Summary, SearchPanel, TotalItem, Pager } from 'devextreme-react/data-grid';
import 'devextreme/data/array_store';
import { CheckBox, SelectBox, Button, Popup } from 'devextreme-react';
import Form, { GroupItem, SimpleItem, ButtonItem } from 'devextreme-react/form';
import './stackplan.scss';
import { formatMessage } from 'devextreme/localization';
import TemporaryStack from './temporarystack';

function StackPlan({ tokenDetails, operation, updateDumpingAreaDetails, onRowSelect }) {

  const [stackData, setStackData] = useState([]);

  const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState({
    selectedGodown: "0",
    popupVisible: false,
    isAllBagTypeStacks: false,
    isCheckboxVisible: true,
    isReadOnly: true
  })

  const [otherStackValues, setOtherStackValues] = useState({
    godownList: [],
    stackList: [],
    selectedShedValue: "",
    selectedStackValue: "",
  })

  const allowedPageSizes = [10, 25, 50, formatMessage('All')];

  useEffect(() => {
    FetchStackData();
    async function FetchStackData() {
      const response = await useGetAPI(
        apis.GET_STACK_PLANS(tokenDetails.genericid, tokenDetails.tokenid, tokenDetails.truckNum, initialValues.isAllBagTypeStacks, operation)
      );
      if (response) {
        const processedStackData = response.data.map((item, index) => ({
          ...item,
          continuousIndex: index + 1,
          flag: item.flagRecordExists ? true : null
        }));
        setStackData(processedStackData);
        setInitialValues(previousValues => ({
          ...previousValues,
          isCheckboxVisible: !processedStackData.some((stack) => stack.readOnlyTable),
          isReadOnly: processedStackData.some((stack) => stack.readOnlyTable)
        }))
        processedStackData.filter((stack) => stack.flagRecordExists === true).forEach((stack) => {
          if (
            tokenDetails.transactiontype === "CMR" ||
            tokenDetails.transactiontype === "LEVY" ||
            tokenDetails.transactiontype === "BRL_CMR"
          ) {
            GetDumpingAreaDetails(stack.mappedGodownUnitId);
          }
        });
        onRowSelect(processedStackData);
      }
    }
  }, [tokenDetails, initialValues.isAllBagTypeStacks]);


  const GetDumpingAreaDetails = async (godownId) => {
    try {
      let dumpingAreaData = await useGetAPI(apis.GET_DUMPINGAREA_ASSOCIATED_WITH_GODOWN(godownId, tokenDetails.genericid));
      if (dumpingAreaData && dumpingAreaData.data) {
        dumpingAreaData.data.readOnly = initialValues.isReadOnly;
        updateDumpingAreaDetails(dumpingAreaData.data);
      } else {
        console.error("Invalid or null data received from the API:");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching RO Details:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleCheckBox = (checkboxvalue, rowData) => {

    const stackId = rowData.data.mappedStacksId;
    const assignedBags = rowData.data.assignedBags;

    setStackData(prevData => {
      const updatedStackData = prevData.map(stack => {
        if (stack.mappedStacksId === stackId) {
          return {
            ...stack,
            flagRecordExists: checkboxvalue,
            assignedBags: checkboxvalue ? assignedBags : null,
            flag: checkboxvalue ? true : null
          };
        }
        return stack;
      });


      if (tokenDetails.transactiontype === "CMR" || tokenDetails.transactiontype === "LEVY" || tokenDetails.transactiontype === "BRL_CMR") {
        GetDumpingAreaDetails(rowData.data.mappedGodownUnitId)
      }
      onRowSelect(updatedStackData);
      return updatedStackData;
    });
  };



  const getUniqueGodowns = () => {
    const godownArray = [{ value: "0", text: formatMessage('AllSheds') }];

    stackData.map((godown) => {
      if (!godownArray.some(option => option.value === godown.godownName)) {
        godownArray.push({ value: godown.godownName, text: godown.godownName });
      }
    });

    return godownArray;
  };


  const renderSelectBox = () => {
    const uniqueGodowns = getUniqueGodowns();
    return (
      <div>
        <SelectBox dataSource={uniqueGodowns} displayExpr="text" valueExpr="value" value={initialValues.selectedGodown} placeholder="select Depot"
          onSelectionChanged={(data) => (setInitialValues(previousValues => ({ ...previousValues, selectedGodown: data.selectedItem.value })))} />

      </div>
    );
  };

  const GetAllShed2 = async () => {
    try {
      const godownListResponse = await useGetAPI(apis.GET_DEPOT_GODOWN_LIST(true));

      if (godownListResponse && godownListResponse.data) {
        const jsonResponse = godownListResponse.data;
        const jsonData = JSON.parse(jsonResponse.substring(jsonResponse.indexOf('(') + 1, jsonResponse.lastIndexOf(')')));
        setOtherStackValues(previousValues => ({ ...previousValues, godownList: jsonData }))
      }

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error fetching godown list:', error);
    }
  };

  const HandleSelectChangeGoDown = async (goDownId) => {
    try {
      let stackOptions = await useGetAPI(
        apis.GET_STACKS_FOR_MULTIPLESTACKING_BY_UNITID(
          goDownId,
          tokenDetails.tokenid,
          tokenDetails.genericid,
          '',
          'Gatepass'
        )
      );

      if (stackOptions && stackOptions.data) {
        const existingStacksOptions = stackData.map((stack) => stack.mappedStacksId);
        const transformedStackList = stackOptions.data
          .filter((stack) => !existingStacksOptions.includes(stack.Stacks_ID))
          .map((stack) => ({
            value: `${stack.Stacks_ID}$${stack.Capacity}$${stack.Gunnycode}`,

            text: stack.Stacks_Name,
          }));

        setOtherStackValues(previousValues => ({ ...previousValues, stackList: transformedStackList }))
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("Error fetching the stack options", error);
    }
  };

  const addOtherStack = () => {
    setOtherStackValues((prevValues) => ({
      ...prevValues,
      selectedShedValue: "",
      selectedStackValue: "",
      godownList: [],
      stackList: []
    }));
    setInitialValues(previousValues => ({ ...previousValues, popupVisible: true }));
    GetAllShed2();
  };

  const handlePopupClose = () => {
    setInitialValues(previousValues => ({ ...previousValues, popupVisible: false }));
  };

  const clearAssignedBagsAndCheckboxValue = () => {
    setStackData((prevData) =>
      prevData.map((stack) => ({
        ...stack,
        flagRecordExists: false,
        assignedBags: null,
      }))
    );
  };

  const handleAddStackClick = () => {
    if (!otherStackValues.selectedShedValue || otherStackValues.selectedShedValue.length === 0) {
      alert(formatMessage('Please_Select_Stack_And_Shed'));
      return;
    }

    if (!otherStackValues.selectedStackValue || otherStackValues.selectedStackValue.length === 0) {
      alert(formatMessage('Please_Select_Stack'));
      return;
    }

    const selectedShedName = otherStackValues.godownList.find((godown) => godown.id === otherStackValues.selectedShedValue)?.value;
    const selectedStackName = otherStackValues.stackList.find((stack) => stack.value === otherStackValues.selectedStackValue)?.text;
    const [stackId, capacity, bagType] = otherStackValues.selectedStackValue.split('$');

    setStackData((prevData) => [
      ...prevData,
      {
        mappedStacksId: parseInt(stackId, 10),
        currentNoOfBags: parseInt(capacity, 10),
        bagtype: bagType,
        mappedGodownUnitId: otherStackValues.selectedShedValue,
        godownName: otherStackValues.selectedShedValue ? selectedShedName : null,
        stackName: selectedStackName ? selectedStackName : null,
        flagRecordExists: false,
        continuousIndex: stackData.length + 1,
      },
    ]);

    // Clear checkbox selection after adding a new stack
    clearAssignedBagsAndCheckboxValue();
    setInitialValues(previousValues => ({ ...previousValues, selectedGodown: selectedShedName }));

    // Close the popup
    handlePopupClose();
  };

  const handleAssignedBagsChange = (e, stackId) => {
    setStackData((prevData) => {
      const updatedStackData = prevData.map((stack) => {
        if (stack.mappedStacksId === stackId) {
          return {
            ...stack,
            assignedBags: e.target.value,
          };
        }
        return stack;
      });
      onRowSelect(updatedStackData);
      return updatedStackData;
    });
  };

  const handleRowPrepared = (e) => {
    if (e.rowType === 'data' && e.data && e.data.flagRecordExists) {
      e.rowElement.classList.add('highlighted-row');
    }
  };

  const isTemporarystackused = (data) => {
    setStackData((prevData) => {
      const updatedStackData = prevData.map((stack) => {
        if (stack.isTemporaryStackUsed !== data) {
          return {
            ...stack,
            isTemporaryStackUsed: data,
          };
        }
        return stack;
      });
      onRowSelect(updatedStackData);
      return updatedStackData;
    });
  }

  const temporaryStacksJSON = (data) => {
    setStackData((prevData) => {
      const updatedStackData = prevData.map((stack) => {
        if (stack.temporaryStacksJSON !== data) {
          return {
            ...stack,
            temporaryStacksJSON: data,
          };
        }
        return stack;
      });
      onRowSelect(updatedStackData);
      return updatedStackData;
    });
  }
  return (
    <>
      <div className="toolbar-container">
        <CheckBox
          text={formatMessage('AllBagTypeStacks')}
          onValueChanged={(e) => {
            setInitialValues(previousValues => ({ ...previousValues, isAllBagTypeStacks: e.value, selectedGodown: "0" }))
          }}
          value={initialValues.isAllBagTypeStacks}
          style={{ zIndex: 1 }}
        />
        <Button
          icon='plus'
          text={formatMessage('AddOtherStack')}
          onClick={addOtherStack}
          className='button-style'
        />
      </div>

      <Popup
        visible={initialValues.popupVisible}
        onHiding={handlePopupClose}
        dragEnabled={true}
        showTitle={true}
        title={formatMessage('AddStack')}
        width="30vw"
        height="25vh"
      >
        <Form>
          <GroupItem colCount={2} >
            <SimpleItem
              dataField={formatMessage('Shed')}
              editorType="dxSelectBox"
              editorOptions={{
                dataSource: otherStackValues.godownList,
                valueExpr: "id",
                displayExpr: "value",
                value: otherStackValues.selectedShedValue,
                onValueChanged: (e) => {
                  setOtherStackValues(previousValues => ({ ...previousValues, selectedShedValue: e.value }))
                  HandleSelectChangeGoDown(e.value);
                },
              }}
            />

            <SimpleItem
              dataField={formatMessage('Stack')}
              editorType="dxSelectBox"
              editorOptions={{
                dataSource: otherStackValues.stackList,
                valueExpr: "value",
                displayExpr: "text",
                value: otherStackValues.selectedStackValue,
                onValueChanged: (e) => {
                  setOtherStackValues(previousValues => ({ ...previousValues, selectedStackValue: e.value }))
                }

              }}
            />
          </GroupItem>
          <ButtonItem horizontalAlignment="right" buttonOptions={{
            text: formatMessage('AddStack'), type: 'default', useSubmitBehavior: true,
            onClick: handleAddStackClick
          }} />
        </Form>
      </Popup>

      <div className='datagrid-container'>
        <DataGrid dataSource={parseInt(initialValues.selectedGodown) === 0 ? stackData : stackData.filter(stack => (parseInt(stack.godownName) === parseInt(initialValues.selectedGodown)))}
          showBorders={true}
          onRowPrepared={(e) => handleRowPrepared(e)}
        >
          <SearchPanel
            visible={true}
            width={240}
            placeholder={formatMessage('Search')}
          />
          <Paging defaultPageSize={10} />
          <Pager
            visible={true}
            allowedPageSizes={allowedPageSizes}
            displayMode="full"
            showInfo={true}
            showPageSizeSelector={true} />
          <Column dataField="continuousIndex" caption={formatMessage('SNo')} allowEditing={false} alignment='left' />
          <Column dataField="godownName" caption={formatMessage('Godown')} width={200} allowSorting={false} alignment='left'
          //headerCellRender={renderSelectBox}
          />
          <Column dataField="stackName" caption={formatMessage('StackName')} allowEditing={false} alignment='left' />
          <Column dataField="bagtype" caption={formatMessage('BagType')} allowEditing={false} alignment='left' />
          <Column dataField="currentNoOfBags" caption={formatMessage('AvailableSpace')} allowEditing={false} alignment='left' />
          <Column
            caption={formatMessage('AssignedBags')}
            dataField="assignedBags"
            alignment='left'
            cellRender={(rowData) => (
              <input
                type="number"
                readOnly={initialValues.isReadOnly || !rowData.data.flagRecordExists}
                defaultValue={rowData.data.assignedBags || ''}
                onBlur={(e) => handleAssignedBagsChange(e, rowData.data.mappedStacksId)}
                onKeyDown={(e) => {
                  if (e.key === 'Enter') {
                    e.preventDefault();
                  }
                }}
              />
            )}
          />
          <Column
            allowEditing={false}
            caption="#"
            cellRender={(rowData) => (

              <CheckBox value={rowData.data.flagRecordExists} visible={initialValues.isCheckboxVisible} onValueChanged={(e) => handleCheckBox(e.value, rowData)} />)}
          />
          <Summary>

            <TotalItem
              column="assignedBags"
              summaryType="sum"
              customizeText={(itemInfo) => `Total Bags : ${itemInfo.value}`}
            />
          </Summary>

        </DataGrid>
        <br />

        <TemporaryStack
          tokenDetails={tokenDetails}
          operation={operation}
          isTempUsed={isTemporarystackused}
          temporaryStacksJSON={temporaryStacksJSON}
        />

      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default React.memo(StackPlan);
```

I had noticed that the error might be caused by isTemporarystackused,temporaryStacksJSON. if not please let me know.
this is my inweight component that i have using props from stackplan throught VisibilityPlan's handleStackData

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, useCallback } from 'react';
import Form, { GroupItem, SimpleItem, ButtonItem } from 'devextreme-react/form';
import apis from '../../../utilities/api-constants';
import TokenSelection from '../../../utilities/token-selection';
import { formatMessage } from 'devextreme/localization';
import PostAPI from '../../../utilities/postAPIS';
import GetAPI from '../../../utilities/getAPIS';
import VisibilityPlan from '../../../utilities/visibilityPlan';
import { DataGrid, Column } from 'devextreme-react/data-grid';
import { Button, RadioGroup, SelectBox } from 'devextreme-react';

export default function Inweight() {
  const [initialValues, setInitialValues] = useState({
    tokenDetails: '',
    aplStackplans: '',
    operation: 'Inweight',
    selectedOptions: '',
    dumpingAreaDetails: [],
    selectedDumpingArea: '0',
    Pvdata: '',
    temporaryStacksJSON: null
  })

  const handleTokenChanges = (tokenDetails, selectedOptions) => {
    setInitialValues(previousValues => ({ ...previousValues, selectedOptions: selectedOptions, tokenDetails: tokenDetails }))
  }
  const handleStackData = (selectedStackData) => {
    const arrangedData = selectedStackData.map(row => ({
      bagtype: row.bagtype,
      isPriorityOverride: row.isPriorityOverride,
      issilo: row.issilo,
      isTemporaryStackUsed: row.isTemporaryStackUsed,
      flagRecordExists: row.flagRecordExists,
      mappedGenericId: initialValues.tokenDetails.genericid,
      mappedGodownUnitId: row.mappedGodownUnitId,
      tokenId: initialValues.tokenDetails.tokenid,
      mappedStacksId: row.mappedStacksId,
      assignedBags: row.assignedBags,
      truckNum: initialValues.tokenDetails.truckNum,
      priority: row.priority,
      cropyear: row.cropyear,
      specificationId: row.specificationId,
      tareweight: row.tareweight,
      specification: row.specification,
      bagCapacity: row.bagCapacity,
      category: row.category,
    }));
    const filteredStackplans = arrangedData.filter(plan => plan.flagRecordExists === true);
    setInitialValues(previousValues => ({ ...previousValues, aplStackplans: filteredStackplans }))
    const tempstackdata = selectedStackData[0]?.temporaryStacksJSON
    setInitialValues(previous => ({ ...previous, temporaryStacksJSON: tempstackdata }))
  };
  function scanWeight() {
    if (!initialValues.inweight) {
      const scannedWeight = parseFloat(window.prompt('Enter the weight'));
      if (scannedWeight) {
        setInitialValues((previous) => ({ ...previous, tokenDetails: { ...previous.tokenDetails, inweight: scannedWeight } }))
      }
    }
  }

  function handleScanAgain() {
    setInitialValues((previous) => ({ ...previous, tokenDetails: { ...previous.tokenDetails, inweight: 0 } }))
  }

  const handlerforPVtype = (gathereddata) => {
    setInitialValues((prevValues) => {
      if (prevValues.Pvdata !== gathereddata) {
        return { ...prevValues, Pvdata: gathereddata };
      } else {
        return prevValues;
      }
    });
  };

  const updateDumpingAreaDetails = (value) => {
    setInitialValues((prevValues) => ({ ...prevValues, dumpingAreaDetails: value }));
  }

  const updateSelectedDumpingArea = (newSelectedDumpingArea) => {
    setInitialValues((prevValues) => ({
      ...prevValues,
      selectedDumpingArea: newSelectedDumpingArea,
    }))
  };

  const HandleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let formatDataforapi
    if (initialValues.tokenDetails.transactiontype === 'PHYSICAL_VERIFICATION') {
      formatDataforapi = {
        wbweight: {
          inweight: initialValues.tokenDetails.inweight,
          mappedStackhistoryId: initialValues.Pvdata.stackHistoryId,
          trucknum: initialValues.tokenDetails.truckNum,
        },
        generic: {
          issilo: false,
          isbagtypemix: false,
          transactiontype: initialValues.tokenDetails.transactiontype,
          noofbags: 0,
        },
        tokenId: initialValues.tokenDetails.tokenid,

      }
    } else if (['MANDI', 'BRL_CMR', 'CMR', 'TRUCKSHIPMENTINWARD'].includes(initialValues.tokenDetails.transactiontype)) {
      formatDataforapi = {
        wbweight: {
          inweight: initialValues.tokenDetails.inweight,
          trucknum: initialValues.tokenDetails.truckNum,
        },
        generic: {
          aplStackplans: initialValues.aplStackplans,
          issilo: false,
          isbagtypemix: false,
          tempStackplans: initialValues.temporaryStacksJSON,
        },
        tokenId: initialValues.tokenDetails.tokenid,
      }
    } else {
      formatDataforapi = {
        wbweight: {
          inweight: initialValues.tokenDetails.inweight,
          trucknum: initialValues.tokenDetails.truckNum,
        },
        generic: {
          aplStackplans: initialValues.aplStackplans,
        },
        tokenId: initialValues.tokenDetails.tokenid,
      }
    }

    let apiResult = await PostAPI(apis.ADD_INWEIGHT(initialValues.tokenDetails.transactiontype), formatDataforapi);
    if (apiResult.status === 200) {
      alert(apiResult.data)
    }

    setInitialValues({
      tokenDetails: '',
      aplStackplans: '',
      operation: 'Inweight',
      selectedOptions: '',
      dumpingAreaDetails: [],
      selectedDumpingArea: '0',
      Pvdata: '',
      temporaryStacksJSON: null
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className={'content-block'}>
      <div className={'dx-card responsive-paddings'}>
        <form onSubmit={HandleSubmit}>
          <Form id="form">
            <GroupItem caption={formatMessage('InWeight')}>
              <GroupItem colCount={2}>
                <GroupItem colSpan={2}>
                  {/* token select part */}
                  <TokenSelection
                    selectedOptions={initialValues.selectedOptions}
                    operation='Inweight'
                    handleTokenChanges={handleTokenChanges}
                    Url={apis.GET_TOKENS_FOR_INWEIGHT}
                  />
                </GroupItem>
              </GroupItem>

            </GroupItem>

            {initialValues.tokenDetails.processType !== 'OTHERS' && (
              <GroupItem>
                <VisibilityPlan
                  tokenDetails={initialValues.tokenDetails}
                  handleStackData={handleStackData}
                  dumpingAreaDetails={initialValues.dumpingAreaDetails}
                  updateDumpingAreaDetails={updateDumpingAreaDetails}
                  updateSelectedDumpingArea={updateSelectedDumpingArea}
                  operation='Inweight'
                />
              </GroupItem>)}

            <GroupItem>
              {initialValues.tokenDetails.transactiontype === 'PHYSICAL_VERIFICATION' &&
                <PHYSICAL_VERIFICATION
                  tokenDetails={initialValues.tokenDetails}
                  exitdata={handlerforPVtype} />}
            </GroupItem>

            {initialValues.tokenDetails && <GroupItem>
              <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                {<label style={{ marginRight: '10px' }}>{['ISSUE', 'PHYSICAL_VERIFICATION'].includes(initialValues.tokenDetails.transactiontype) ? formatMessage("Tare_Weight_in_Qtls") : formatMessage("Gross_Weight_in_Qtls")}</label>}
                {!initialValues.tokenDetails.inweight ? <Button onClick={scanWeight} text={formatMessage('Capture_Weight')} /> : ''}
                {initialValues.tokenDetails.inweight ? (
                  <div>
                    <input type='text' value={initialValues.tokenDetails.inweight} readOnly style={{ marginRight: '10px' }} />
                    <Button onClick={handleScanAgain} icon='refresh' />
                  </div>
                ) : ''}
              </div>
            </GroupItem>}
            <ButtonItem horizontalAlignment="left" buttonOptions={{ text: formatMessage('Save'), type: 'success', useSubmitBehavior: true }} />
          </Form>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try removing state update of other components that are passing as props. Update the state of stack plan and pass the data from the props to the parent component.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).